# GetOrgChart and the company behind it

Tags: getorgchart

We are looking to purchase a license of GetOrgChartJS for a project we are working on.   We noticed they just adjusted their pricing.

However, before we commit to the Professional or Enterprise licenses, we'd like to know a little bit more about the company behind the product.

Where are they located?   How big is the company?  How many people do they have on staff?   If someone on the staff of getOrgChart could comment here, that would be great.

We really like the product so far, and if we could find out more about the people behind, we'll be more than happy to get a license.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Just my 2 cents... I have not received any response from the company after making a few inquiries into some of the technical details of the product, nor have I seen much activity from them in terms of answering product questions here. It's been a few weeks, but nonetheless, they advertise on their website that stackoverflow is the place to go with answers, but you don't see much activity from them. Also, given the limitations of the product (and nothing to indicate that they're addressing these issues), I moved away from it as have others.

Comment: Thanks for the information.   If you moved away from GetOrgChart, what did you use in it's place?     We spent quite a bit of time looking for something that was easy to use and enhance.   And this looked promising.    We're definitely not married to GetOrgChart, so if there was something else out there that was open-source, or commercial, we'd be interested in testing those solutions out.   Thanks!

Comment: I used to work for GetOrgChart. Actually it is quite nice company. They are not answering because they have many customers requests. Also now they are working on a new project GetOrgChart with lazy loading and many new requested features from clients